# "Tired from work" or "tired from working"?

Tags: word-choice, gerunds

Tell me please which one is it correct to use in the following context.

> I have been working all day. I am so tired from **work**/**working**.

Comment: I am so tired from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more natural to say "tired from work" rather than "tired from working", if it's a casual conversation, based on my experience. "Tired from working" is grammatically correct, however.

In your specific context, to give the meaning that you want, I would say it sounds more natural to simply say "I am so tired from it", or even "I am so tired" because the reason for being tired would probably be understood from the previous sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In the context you gave, "I am so tired from working" would be the appropriate phrasing. This sentence says that, because you have been working, you are tired. However, "I am so tired from work" is also a valid sentence; it states that you are tired because of the object 'work,' which is a common way to refer to one's career or occupation.